# Automating R data.frames to CREATE TABLE statements

Tags: sql, r, database, postgresql, dataframe

I am primarily an `R` programmer but I have been learning `Postgres`/`PostGIS` in the past few months and I haven't been able to reconcile why there a tool/function hasn't been created to import R `data.frames` directly into the database, given that they can hold data types for each column. I imagine the tool would:

1. Make the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the data first, taking into account the data types of the columns.
2. Accept any parameters from the user to use constrictive character limits to columns or loose character limits according to the user,
3. Allow for defining a primary key, and any other requirements for the table
4. Update the table with the data in the data.frame.

The data types in R are more limited than Postgres but I think that this kind of importing would be valuable. Maybe even generating the .sql file from the data frame instead of interacting directly? I'm interested if someone could tell me why this would be a bad idea before I try to build this kind of functionality for myself.

My main reason for building this kind of tool would be be to automate my import process from working in R to the database. Maybe kind of functionality exists already somewhere else? Writing the CREATE TABLE statements seems to be the "by hand" work that I would like to avoid when I can and I'm trying to find a way to speed up this process for new projects.

Comment: [RODBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf)? Not sure if it works with postgresql

Comment: Will rodbc automate the create table statement with other databases?

Comment: I believe so, but I don't know. That's why I put a question mark in my comment. It's also why I linked the documentation.

Comment: @cyclondude open the link alex posted, ctrl+f and look for write (as in write table). The first result should take you to `sqlSave`

Comment: RODBC has has a `sqlUpdate` method that could be of use.  The `RPostgreSQL` package has `dbWriteTable` that would be worth looking into (it is an extension of `DBI`'s `dbWriteTable`, if I remember correctly.